# .net c# text box date with mask - setup

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, input

I have a c# .net project and want an input text box for a date value.  I want it to display a default value of mm/dd/yyyy and then allow users to enter valid dates.

I have tried using a masked text box but it doesn't like having the above format.

If i try and use **/**/____ looks naff and so does 00/00/0000 and of course if you put in '0' like 03/11/2009 you get 3/11/29 because the 0's are deleted as part of the mask.

What is the best way to set up an input box like this, effectively with a mask, only allowing numbers, and validation (though at this point I am not so worried about that).

This seems so simple and isn't.

Comment: I asked a similar question (but specifically about the AjaxControlToolkit's MaskedEditExtender) - the accepted answer may be useful in your scenario as well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837200/ajaxcontroltoolkit-maskededitextender-custom-mask-appearance

Comment: I have assumed Windows Forms in my answer, as no platform was specified.

Comment: Are you planning to localize this application?

Answer (score 1):

Try examining the the date in the OnChange event. Check the length of the text, adding / when appropriate.

Alternatively, see if the the DatePicker may be a better choice...

Answer (score 0):

Why not try and use a plugin like the jQuery UI DatePicker?

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker

They are lightweight, tested and saves work!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Windows Forms, the [DateTimePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx) is the tool for the job.

Here is an example with the [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx), but since you say it doesn't work...

Another good try, if you're using `DataBinding`, if by instantiating a [Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.aspx) ([Binding for WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.aspx)) class and handling its [Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.parse.aspx) and [Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.format.aspx) events (these don't seem to exist in WPF, but there must be some way).

In short:

```
Binding b = new Binding("Text", BindingSourceInstance, "data.DateCreated");
b.Parse += new EventHandler(b_Parse);
b.Format += new EventHandler(b_Format);

private void b_Format(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e) {
    if (e.DesiredType != typeof(DateTime)) return;

    e.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    // Or you may prefer some other variants:
    // e.Value.ToShortDateString();
    // e.Value.ToLongDateString();
    // e.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeInfo.ShortDatePattern);
}

private void b_Parse(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e) {
    // Choose whether you to handle perhaps bad input formats...

    e.Value = DateTime.Parse(e.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // The CultureInfo here may be whatever you choose.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using masked text box for date is a headache, best to use `DateTime.TryParseExact()` with control validated event.

It will guarantee user input in correct format without too much coding, like in this example:

you need to use also a `ToolTip` to instruct the user to the correct input.

```
private void txtEntryDate_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEntryDate.Text))
       {
         DateTime entryDate;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(txtEntryDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out entryDate))
       {
         // further actions for validations
       }
       else
       {
       setTooltip(txtEntryDate, "txtEntryDate", "Invalid date format date must be formatted to dd/MM/yyyy");
                txtEntryDate.Focus();
        }
        }
        else
        {
        setTooltip(txtEntryDate, "txtEntryDate", "Please provide entry date in the format of dd/MM/yyyy");
        txtEntryDate.Focus();
        }
       }
```

and the `ToolTip` class:

```
private void setTooltip(Control Ctrl, string CtrlCaption, string ToolTipMsg)
        {
            ToolTip tt1 = new ToolTip();
            tt1.AutoPopDelay = 5000;
            tt1.InitialDelay = 1000;
            tt1.ReshowDelay = 500;
            tt1.ShowAlways = false;
            tt1.SetToolTip(Ctrl, CtrlCaption);
            tt1.Show(ToolTipMsg, Ctrl,5000);
        }
```